# Get inputs from edit TextBoxes when pressing Update on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the values from text fields when pressing the update button on a gridview:
[image]

The following results in no output:

```
protected void viewStoryTime_OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(entry.Value);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the entry to retrieve the value from the dictionary, thats the problem:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
{

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.NewValues[entry.Key])

}
```